# how can i input multiple numbers or strings only at once to append them to a list?

Tags: python, arraylist, raw-input

I need to repeat the process of inputting the numbers as many as mentioned in the variable `number`:

```
number = int(input("How many numbers do you want in your list? "))
list = [for i in range(0,number)]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `lst = list(range(number))` works...

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do:

```
my_list = [int(input("Enter number {}... ".format(i+1))) for i in range(0,number)]
```

Here, `my_list` will hold the `list` of `n` numbers entered by the user.

*Note:* `list` is built-in type in Python. Do not use it as variable name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a bunch inputted at once, separated by commas, you could use:

```
w = input("Enter stuff to add to the list, separated by commas.")
my_list = w.split(",")
print(my_list)
```

This code accepts input as comma-separated stuff like this: `a, 1, @^` and turns it into this: `['a', '1', '@^']` The code works by accepting comma-ed input as `w`, then splitting it into a list by the commas, using the built in `split()` method.